# Error with Spring locating classes using STS eclipse, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, web-services, rest

I'm new to Spring framework. I'm working on this web service tutorial, but I'm having some problems.
Take a look at the project structure below:

[image: project structure]

At first, while I was following the tutorial I created new classes in the bookmarks package, since that's where the Application file was located. However, when I did this then I couldn't import a lot of the packages required for the tutorial. I spent some time trying to figure out if I'd missed something in the project settings, or there was an error in Gradle or something (another thing I haven't used before) but I couldn't find any issues.

I noticed if I moved the files concerned to the folder src/main then all the imports could be found without any issues. 
So I carried on with the tutorial; however, when ever I tried to add a new file to the src/main folder, buy right-clicking it, selecting new java file, etc... eclipse always puts the file in the src/main/java folder and again imports cannot be found. 
So again, I manually move the files to src/main.

The File WebServiceDemo3Application.java was auto-generated by the project, so that has to be in the correct location.

But after adding code to it, it cannot locate the files Account.java, Bookmark.java, etc...

[image: application.java error]

It must be something silly that I'm overlooking, can anyone help?

Comment: Move your classes. They hould be in the `src/main/java` folder not in `src/main` folder. This has nothing to do with Spring but that is how Gradle (and also maven) expects the project structure to be (by default).

Comment: OK, when I do that, then Eclipse can't find `javax.persistance.Entity`, `GeneratedValue`, `Id`, `ManyToOne` - which is why I moved the files into the `src/main` folder to test in the first place. Also, it can't find `org.springframework.data` (from which I need `.jpa.repository.JpaRepository`), but it has no problem finding those from the other folder. Got any ideas? thanks!

Comment: Also, I'll obviously need to spend a good bit of time researching Gradle.

Comment: Actually it's pretty much all of javax.persistance that's missing

Comment: I strongly suggest you take some time investigating gradle. YOu are missing dependencies in your gradle file. The ones that provide `javax.persistence` classes and other `org.springframework` classes. Add those. Moving files to another folder doesn't solve your problem it just doesn't see those classes anymore.

Comment: OK, I made the assumption that because I made the new project using   new -> Spring Starter Project it would include all those dependencies, but that isn't the case?

Comment: No it will include basic dependencies but it will not include every possible combination of dependencies. If you need other things you need to add them yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your help @M.Deinum I've resolved my issues. It's a lot to take in when your trying to learn so many tools together! Would you care to provide an official answer that I can accept?